# openlayers bootstrap3 examples?

Tags: openlayers-2, bootstrap-framework

I was wondering if there is any good example of openlayers used in the HTML page with bootstrap3?

I searched around, and can only find bootstrap 2 examples, like this one: http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/bootstrap.html

I adapted my first map application from one of those examples. But when I tried to switch to bootstrap3, the layout was a mess. What used to be on my right half of the page now displays at the bottom beyond the normal viewport. Since my web page isn't that complex. I think it might be easier if I transfer the content to a bootstrap3 openlayers example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used the templates at http://themapguyde.blogspot.co.uk/2014/08/bootstrap-map-viewer-templates.html to quickly produce a Bootstrap and OpenLayers 3 map.

The source is on GitHub at https://github.com/jumpinjackie/bootstrap-viewer-template.

Answer (score 1):

Map viewer development with Bootstrap3 and OpenLayers5:

http://visorgeo.ambientebogota.gov.co/